# Spying & mocking return values on ctors & methods in node module with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

After much trial/error, searching here on SO, & flexing my Google Fu, throwing in the towel & asking for help.

**TL/DR** -
Trying to correctly mock node module, change internal method return types, and spy on ctor's & method calls within the node module.

My specific scenario is to test the Microsoft Azure Storage blob SDK [@azure/storage-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob), but the questions aren't specific to this package. It's just a good example as 4 LOC's capture achieve a task (upload a file to a storage container) as 2-3 of those LOC's cover 4 scenarios. Here's my code that I want to test, with comments on WHAT exactly I want to test:

```js
export async function saveImage(account: string, container: string, imageBuffer: Buffer, imageName: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    // init storage client
    // (1) want to spy on args passed into ctor
    const blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    // init container
    // (2) same as #1
    const containerClient: ContainerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
    // init block blob client
    // (3) same as #1 & #2
    const blockBlobClient: BlockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(imageName);
    // save file
    // (4) same as #1,2, & 3
    // (5) manipulate returned value
    // (6) throw cause method to internally throw error
    await blockBlobClient.upload(imageBuffer, imageBuffer.length, { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/png' } });

    return Promise.resolve();
  } catch (err: Error) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}
```

I've setup a manual mock for the module in the ./__mocks/@azure/storage-blob.ts as follows:

```js
const MockStorageBlob = jest.createMockFromModule('@azure/storage-blob');

/**
 * Utility method throw exception in the `BlockBlobClient.upload()` method.
 */
(MockStorageBlob as any).__setBlockBlobUpload_toFail = () => {
  (MockStorageBlob as any).BlobServiceClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getContainerClient: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        getBlockBlobClient: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
          upload: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            throw new Error('synthetic error');
          })
        })
      })
    }
  });
}

module.exports = MockStorageBlob;
```

In my test, I can successfully test for #6 above like this:

```js
import {
  BlockBlobClient,
  BlockBlobUploadResponse
} from '@azure/storage-blob';
import { saveImageToCDN as functionUnderTest } from './saveImageToCDN';

// mock Azure Storage blob NPM package
jest.mock('@azure/storage-blob');

describe('check expected with failure', () => {

  beforeEach((done) => {
    // reset number of times things have been called
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    done();
  });

  test(`it calls 'trackException()' when upload throws exception`, async (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    // setup test
    require('@azure/storage-blob').__setBlockBlobUpload_toFail();

    // run SUT
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from('test string');
    functionUnderTest(imageBuffer, 'imageName.png')
      .then(() => {
        expect(new Error('should not reach this')).toBeUndefined();
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        expect(err).toBeDefined();
      })
      .finally(() => {
        done();
      });
  });

});
```

... but I can't figure out the correct syntax to spy on the `upload()` method (#4), or any of the other things I'm trying to test for (#1-5). If it matters, using Jest v26 on Node v14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the `__setBlockBlobUpload_toFail` function return references to the mock functions ?

That would give something like this :

```js
const MockStorageBlob = jest.createMockFromModule('@azure/storage-blob');

/**
 * Utility method throw exception in the `BlockBlobClient.upload()` method.
 */
(MockStorageBlob as any).__setBlockBlobUpload_toFail = () => {
  const upload = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
     throw new Error('synthetic error');
  });
  const getBlockBlobClient = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ upload });
  const getContainerClient = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ getBlockBlobClient });
  const BlobServiceClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getContainerClient
    }
  });

  (MockStorageBlob as any).BlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient;

  return {
    upload,
    getBlockBlobClient,
    getContainerClient,
    BlobServiceClient
  };
}

module.exports = MockStorageBlob;
```

And in your test you would retrieve them like :

```js
// setup test
const mockFns = require('@azure/storage-blob').__setBlockBlobUpload_toFail();

// run SUT
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from('test string');
functionUnderTest(imageBuffer, 'imageName.png')
  .then(() => {
    expect(new Error('should not reach this')).toBeUndefined();
  })
  .catch((err: Error) => {
    expect(mockFns.getBlockBlobClient.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('imageName.png')
    expect(err).toBeDefined();
  })
  .finally(() => {
    done();
  });
```

Comment: Good suggestion... this sent me down the right track. Thanks!